# Firebase database bandwidth usage growing rapidly even when when the database is not in use

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

**Update:** After 9 months of back-and-forth emails (over 40 emails), Google has acknowledged that they have found some bugs that may be responsible for high bandwidth usage, but bandwidth usage is still too high. Resolving this issue does no appear to be a priority for Google/Firebase (it took them 1.5 months to respond to the last email). In light of similar complaints such as: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14356409, and many others, across a wide range of teams/developers, hopefully the situation will improve some day.

---

I'm just starting a Firebase project and have not accessed the database from any client. I have only created a single tiny test key-value pair in the database (using the console), which uses 23 B of data storage. Surprisingly, the console shows that I have used 215.9 KB (including when I was not touching Firebase at all). This number continues to grow every hour even though I am not using Firebase or even refreshing the data tab in the console!

Here is a screenshot of the console bandwidth usage chart:
[Firebase console bandwidth usage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJro1.png)

Others appear to be having the same problem, but there has been no response from Firebase/Google. What's going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible this is bookkeeping storage needed to support the data itself, and it appears that the data related to refreshes are due to session storage. Does it tail off back to a lower level after a certain amount of inactive time?

Comment: @Nick Since I don't work at Google, I wouldn't know if this is bookkeeping data, but if it were, then it's certainly undocumented behavior.  More importantly, it's thousands of times higher than it should be. Also the data usage is all over the place, when it should be close to 0 (the database has never been accessed except from the Firebase console a few times).

Comment: Have you looked into the potential auth issue mentioned by @Chad Baxter in their answer below?

Comment: @Nick As I explained to Chad Baxter earlier (in a comment), the default authentication rules require authentication for reads and writes, so this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Is it not possible that the crawlers' failed attempts to access are causing the bandwidth usage, or that the console's accessing of the database is being recorded? It seems the storage amount is in accordance with what you expect, but the bandwidth is to be explained - is this the case? Do you have access to the host machine the database is running on?

Comment: @Nick Crawlers failing to access the database but affecting bandwidth usage would be a huge (undocumented) flaw in the Firebase platform. I don't think that this is the case here, however, because a link to the database has not been listed anywhere. Yes, the storage amount makes sense, bandwidth doesn't. No one except for Google has access to their machines running their proprietary database.

Comment: Is it possible the console accessing the database to view it is behind the bandwidth usage? There are several tabs which request data from the server, and going through the tabs, refreshing, etc. could cause the issue, it seems.

Comment: @Nick As I explained to Chad Baxter earlier (in a comment): "I'm only storing 23 B in the database and have not read from the database at all in any way from any client. Even if opening the Firebase console and clicking on the database link downloads all of my data and affects my bandwidth, there would be nowhere near 215 KB used. For example, even if I refreshed the console 10 times, that should use no more than 230 B. I would need to refresh the console almost 10,000 times to see the bandwidth numbers I'm seeing."

Comment: Have you considered contacting [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) directly? It appears they may be the most able to resolve this question. See the "contact us" section.

Comment: @Nick We've been discussing this with Google/Firebase for over a month and they have not provided an explanation. They don't have an answer even though many developers and teams who would like to use Firebase have been facing similar problems for a while now.

Comment: Do you currently have an issue open with support?

Comment: could you let me know whether you have an open case with support? If not, I'd like to make sure this gets resolved to your satisfaction.

Comment: @Nick Yes, a case was opened with Firebase support on August 15, 2016. We're still exchanging emails with no resolution.

Comment: Could you email me the case number or the email you're using to correspond at my email: paynen@google.com? I could take a look into the case as well and see if there's anything we can do, or anything more to report here.

Comment: @Nick Emailed you. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any hint about this issue? I'm on the same boat. My database only has 5KB stored but is showing traffic from 1-4MB daily... That's crazy! I'm not downloading these data 200 times in a day!! Moreover, the graph shows traffic even late at night, when nobody is connected to firebase through a client nor checking the console...

Comment: In addition, I created an empty project and is showing 54KB of traffic :| In another blank project I stored about 20bytes, changed the tab (twice I think, no clients) to see usage and 5.19KB is shown (like x200). Something is definitly wrong with this...

Comment: Hey @Pl4yeR, from communicating with Firebase support in regard to OP's issue, it seems that the issue has become stuck due to requiring some diagnostic testing from the user's side. It's unclear if the issue is still occurring for them, as well. I would recommend getting in touch with support immediately through the channels mentioned in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/). You can open 5 cases directly with support per year at this point, and it's a very valuable resource. They should be able to help you from there, especially if you reference this question.

Comment: @Pl4yeR The problem has not been resolved after 2.5 months of back-and-forth emails with Firebase support (they won't acknowledge that there is a problem even after their own tests confirm it), and we're hearing that others are facing this as well.

Comment: Same problem here, database is 300Kb and I have traffic for 4-5MB daily (I'm the only user, test project)

Comment: Exact same issue here, tests show usage of about 40mb when I'm only storing around 4mb. That's 10x what it should be. Any resolutions?

Comment: Same here. 102B for storage but 230KB of download without any query.

Answer (score 3):

The usage chart takes time to update. You may be seeing bandwidth from a few minutes to a few hours ago.

Also, this reminds me of the old Google Analytics referrer issue, the default rules for firebase look something like this:

```
.read = true;
.write if auth != null;
```

This means that anyone anywhere can read from your database and that anyone authenticated(even anonymously) can write to it. It is possible since it is a noSQL database with json support that it is probably just crawlers which are the equivalent of Google Analytics referral spam.

Comment: OP clearly says he used firebase database to insert just a tiny key-value pair and nothing else still the bandwidth usage chart is growing. This needs explanation, I've also noticed the same thing, without using database, the usage keeps on increasing.

Comment: I'm only storing 23 B in the database and have not read from the database at all in any way from any client. Even if opening the Firebase console and clicking on the database link downloads all of my data and affects my bandwidth, there would be nowhere near 215 KB used. For example, even if I refreshed the console 10 times, that should use no more than 230 B. I would need to refresh the console almost 10,000 times to see the bandwidth numbers I'm seeing.

Comment: According to the first paragraph in the Firebase documentation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), both reads and writes would need to be authenticated, so crawlers should not be able to affect bandwidth usage. Also, even if that were not the case (suppose the documentation is wrong), how would crawlers know the structure of my database JSON and be able to read it? I have not deployed anything and there are no links to my database anywhere on the web.

Comment: Exact same problem that I'm having. I provide a little more data, but still do not understand the cause of the problem. My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457341/computing-firebase-message-size