# Is there a certain limit to reading firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am using firebase, and I use it a lot in my app. But I noticed that when I go to my database usage on the console, I have extremely high percentage peaks for the load section (peak of 5,700 %). What's odd is for almost all days it says 1 = 3 % and then one day it hit 5700%. I tried to look around but I could not find anything on what often causes this. I do in fact call the function observeSingleEvent a good amount in my app, and am wondering if this is the cause for my problems. Does calling the observeSingleEvent function cause usage issues if used like 10 - 20 times in my app? I currently have firebase spark plan, maybe that might be the reason. I hoping that this is either not a problem, or can be solved, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38959321/1531971

Comment: idv I did read that article, I also noticed that usage increases when no data is being used. but I am having a problem in the load section of usage, where randomly it spikes to like above 100 percent

Comment: Ok, but you should mention what research you did so we know what it is about those other resources that do or do not apply. In this case, there is a conjecture that there is a bug that is out of your control under some circumstances. I think it bears research to see if there is a similar bug under what circumstances you are are in.